# window.open in background.js Chrome BUG ? It's work in unpacked extension not in PROD (published in the store)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't figure why my code working in DEV environment, when i publish my code it's not work, and made my Chrome Extension crash, and a message said that my extension is corrupted.

Since the latest update of Chrome (73.0.3683.75), we are not able to do cross site call in the content.js, so i need to open a popup to do what i need to do.

I call from the content.js a method in my background.js to open popup.

Content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, { method: "CustomUpload",function(){

            });
```

In my background.js script i received the call and open the popup.

```
case "CustomUpload":
          var w = window.open("/upload.html", "name", 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=250', false);
          w.focus();
          w.addEventListener("load", function () {
            w.InitializeFileHelper();
          }, true);
```

I don't know why, but it's workin in DEV not in prod. Where i miss something ?

**If i activate developper mode, i go get the "extension" and load extension unpackted everything working fine. It's there a bug with chrome ?**

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

I do a lot of test and always the same problem.

I try

```
chrome.windows.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL("upload.html")})
chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL("upload.html") });
window.open(chrome.extension.getURL("/upload.html"));
```

Always same result, working fine "localally" but when it's published stop working and get a message Extension could be corrupted.

I see the popup show up for 1ms and then close and the extension is need to be repair.

Comment: Try chrome.windows.create with type:'popup', and move the code that uploads the file into upload.html's script.

Comment: How i can send parameters from my "background.js" scripts to my upload.html ... i mean, with window.open, i can call a javascript function with my w.InitializeFileHelper(). With chrome.windows.create, did i need to use the tabs.sendmessage to send parameters ?

Comment: See [Append DOM to self chrome extension file opened from popup.js](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: Not work. I just publish my modification based on your recommandation. The popup seen like to open, but close immediatly after.

Comment: It can mean the problematic code is inside the popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm i just publish the code without any code inside the popup and same result. It's look like the "context" kill, and the windows is kill with the "context". Could be the manifest ? Did i need to set something in the "browser_action" ?  If it's work in dev, no reason the manifest could be wrong ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: For me to have an idea of what exactly is happening there I need to look at the extension. Can you share the web store link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190149/discussion-between-cedric-boivin-and-woxxom).

Comment: @wOxxOm f i activate developper mode, i go get the "extension" and load extension unpackted everything working fine. It's there a bug with chrome ?

Comment: It could be a bug in Chrome. However I see you still use window.open in the extension and directly call a function from a different window which isn't a good idea generally - if you ilke window.open approach you should at least use DOM messaging via w.postMessage and onmessage listener in upload.js.

Comment: @wOxxOm, i continue to use the window.open because all the other option do not work. i publish almost 12 different version. window.open, chrome.tabs.create, chrome.windows.create ... always the same result.

Comment: Well, I guess the only way out is to use divide-and-conquer: comment out most of the code and see if it crashes, restore in chunks, test, until it crashes.

Comment: I finally found it. In my popup.html I added an image included in my extension. But for a misterious reason, the extension crash when the image is in the popup. I just removed the image from the popup and now it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was an image in my "upload.html" file.

My image was in the extension, the path was good, but chrome extension was crash when the image was there. Just remove the image, and the extension working well.

Special thanks to @wOxxOm for is help.